# parse json file presented within /static/ - using Django URL

Tags: python, json, django

I am having json file in my django app. I have parsed it to fetch json using `json.loads` and returned as django URL.

I tried this,

```
json_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', "utils/config/AccessConf.json")
data = open(json_file_path, 'r')
parsed_json = json.loads(data.read())
print parsed_json
```

it is working code. but i want to know is there any better/optimized method than this?

Comment: It seems like you are using Python 2. If you are just beginning to learn Python, it may be better to program in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of json.loads, you can use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) which uses the file object directly:

```
data = open(json_file_path, 'r')
parsed_json = json.load(data)
```

This saves a little bit of code, and may save some memory if you have big JSON files.

Furthermore, you could use [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to close the file when done with it:

```
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as data:
    parsed_json = json.load(data)
```

This closes the file as soon as you exit the "with" block.

Comment: i know and tried this method. but i want to know is there anything like URL parsing?

Comment: Yes. If you have a specific question about how to do URL parsing, feel free to ask a new question here that states what you want to do exactly and what you have tried already.